# Importing libgdx gradle project in eclipse giving error

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

When trying to import the a gradle project in eclipse, i get following error. 
[image]

But i am pretty shore I have installed android api 20.

[image]

How do I fix this error?

Some more info:
I created the project on my macbook using libgdx setup-app and now I want to import the project on my desktop computer. I have changed the `local.properties`-file to point to android-sdk directory on my desktop.

Edit: My local.properties looks like this:

```
# Location of the android SDK
#My mac location
#sdk.dir=/Users/Elias/android-sdks
#my pc location:
sdk.dir=C:/android-sdks
```

Comment: Why don't you use Intellij Idea? Its community version is free and fully support LibGDX development, it's by far better than Eclipse.

Comment: The error box tries to find Android SDK at C:\androids-sdks and you say it is in in the android-sdk directory on your Desktop. Looks like you messed up the paths somehow. Go to Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android and copy the path in your local.properties.

Comment: @ThomasPronold Where does it say that is in the android-sdk directory? When going Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android it says `C:\android-sdks`

Comment: Sorry I was wrong the value in Preferences -> Android is read from local.properties. Does your C:\androids-sdks folder contain a folder called "sdk" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of having the good syntax?

the local.properties must be something like

D:\Devs\Android
Be sure to use '\'

I don't see any other issues it could be, also check your sdk android folder in eclipse preferences

Comment: That was not the problem, I have updated the post to show how I did